# ImportError: No module named appengine.ext

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have installed the gcloud components and other packages. But when I ran this command:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle src.service.endpoint_api.APIClass
```

It fails with:

```
WARNING:root:Could not find either the Cloud SDK or the App Engine Python SDK.
If you encounter errors, please make sure that the SDK binary path is in your
PATH environment variable or that the ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK variable points to a
valid SDK root.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 26, in <module>
    import _endpointscfg_setup  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/test/Documents/shipper-dashboard/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 107, in <module>
    _SetupPaths()
  File "/home/test/Documents/shipper-dashboard/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 103, in _SetupPaths
    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure you have correctly installed the gcloud SDk, you can run:

```
gcloud --version
```

and you should receive something like this

```
Google Cloud SDK 272.0.0
alpha 2019.05.17
app-engine-go
app-engine-java 1.9.77
app-engine-php " "
app-engine-python 1.9.87
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.87
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.50
cbt
cloud-build-local
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
cloud_sql_proxy
core 2019.11.16
datalab 20190610
docker-credential-gcr
gsutil 4.46
kubectl 2019.11.04
pubsub-emulator 2019.09.27
```

In case that command is not recognized, please follow this tutorial about [Installing Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) according to your needs, if you are using linux ([Debian/Ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get))([Linux 7/CentOS 7](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-yum)) / [Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker) / [Windows or macOS](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive).

If 'app-engine-python' is not shown when running `gcloud --version`, please follow this instructions to install the [CloudSDK for Pyhton](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download).

In summary, run

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

and

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python-extras
```

If you want to update the Cloud SDK, please run the following command to ensure you have the latest versions:

```
gcloud components update
```

About setting the env var, i.e. in Linux you should run something like this:

```
export ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK=/path/to/appropiate/SDK
```

Comment: gcloud --version is working fine but when i run this command gcloud components update then i got this error You cannot perform this action because the Cloud SDK component manager 
is disabled for this installation.

Comment: source ~/.bashrc After run this it is working but still getting same error

Comment: I have read about this ([StackExchange Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146879/how-do-i-fix-the-google-cloud-sdk-component-manager-is-disabled-for-this-instal)), the solution would be remove the gcloud SDK: `sudo apt purge autoremove google-cloud-sdk` and then install again ([SDK QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)), by download the correct `.tar.gz`, extract it `tar -xzf google-cloud-sdk-*` to a dir, and then install it by running: `sudo ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`. Once this is finishedm restart the terminal and then run `gcloud components update`.